# Hibernate error in Liferay

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay and here are my classes and methods in them:

**`EmployeeLocalServiceImpl.java`**

```java
public class EmployeeLocalServiceImpl extends EmployeeLocalServiceBaseImpl {
    /*
     * NOTE FOR DEVELOPERS:
     *
     * Never reference this interface directly. Always use {@link com.mallyas.corpserver.emco.mis.service.EmployeeLocalServiceUtil} to access the employee local service.
     */

    public List getEmployee() throws PortalException, SystemException, RemoteException {

        return EmployeeFinderUtil.getEmployee();
    }
 ...
}
```

**`EmployeeFinderImpl.java`**

```java
public class EmployeeFinderImpl extends BasePersistenceImpl<Employee> implements EmployeeFinder {

    // the name of the query
    public static String GET_EMPLOYEE = "getemployee";

    // the method which will be called from the ServiceImpl class

    public List<Employee> getEmployee() throws SystemException {

        Session session = null;
        try {
            // open a new hibernate session
            session = openSession();


            String fetchEmpsqlquery = CustomSQLUtil.get(GET_EMPLOYEE);

            // create a SQLQuery object
            SQLQuery empqueryObj = session.createSQLQuery(fetchEmpsqlquery);

            // replace the "Book" in the query string with the fully qualified java class
            // this has to be the hibernate table name
            empqueryObj.addEntity("Employee", EmployeeImpl.class);


            // Get query position instance
            QueryPos qPos = QueryPos.getInstance(empqueryObj);

            // fill in the "?" value of the custom query
            // this is same like forming a prepared statement
            //qPos.add(pattern);

            // execute the query and return a list from the db
            return (List<Employee>)empqueryObj.list();

            /*
            // use this block if you want to return the no. of rows (count)

            int rows = 0;

            Iterator<Long> itr = q.list().iterator();

            if (itr.hasNext()) { Long count = itr.next();

            if (count != null) { rows = count.intValue(); } }

            return rows;
            */
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SystemException(e);
        } finally {
            closeSession(session);
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

**`EmployeeFinder.java`**

```java
@Transactional
public interface EmployeeFinder {

    public java.util.List<com.mallyas.corpserver.emco.mis.model.Employee> getEmployee()
        throws com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException;
}
```

**`EmployeeFinderUtil.java`**

```java
@Transactional
public class EmployeeFinderUtil {

    public static java.util.List<com.mallyas.corpserver.emco.mis.model.Employee> getEmployee()
        throws com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException {
        return getFinder().getEmployee();
    }

    public static EmployeeFinder getFinder() {
        if (_finder == null) {
            _finder = (EmployeeFinder)PortletBeanLocatorUtil.locate(com.mallyas.corpserver.emco.mis.service.ClpSerializer.getServletContextName(),
                    EmployeeFinder.class.getName());

            ReferenceRegistry.registerReference(EmployeeFinderUtil.class,
                "_finder");
        }

        return _finder;
    }

    public void setFinder(EmployeeFinder finder) {
        _finder = finder;

        ReferenceRegistry.registerReference(EmployeeFinderUtil.class, "_finder");
    }

    private static EmployeeFinder _finder;
```

I get the following error when I run this application:

```java
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-9][render_portlet_jsp:154] com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    at com.mallyas.corpserver.emco.mis.service.persistence.EmployeeFinderImpl.getEmployee(EmployeeFinderImpl.java:69)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardPersistenceAdvice.invoke(ShardPersistenceAdvice.java:52)
    at com.mallyas.corpserver.emco.mis.service.persistence.EmployeeFinderUtil.getEmployee(EmployeeFinderUtil.java:29)
    at com.mallyas.corpserver.emco.mis.service.impl.EmployeeLocalServiceImpl.getEmployee(EmployeeLocalServiceImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.displayData.dbcheck_jsp._jspService(dbcheck_jsp.java:172)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
```

What could possibly be wrong?
I have included @Transactional in each of the above classes, I also tried removing @Transactional from all the classes but I still get the same error..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following property in the hibernate configuration:

```
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
```

This will basically bound the session on per-thread basis.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're probably getting these exception while calling a method from the FinderImpl or Finder Class. I'm also guessing that you're using the Finder Class to perform a custom query. let that method be named 'getEmployeeByCustom'

You don't need to edit the Finder.java or FinderUtil.java Classes, just the FinderImpl.java one.

make sure to use a wrapper function in your EmployeeLocalServiceImpl

```
    public List<Employee> getEmployeeByCustom(.....) 
        throws SystemException {

    return EmployeeFinderUtil.getEmployeeByCustom(....);

}
```

Then, call the 'getEmployeeByCustom' through EmployeeLocalServiceUtil.getEmployeeByCustom(...)

You should undo the 'Transactional' related edits, you are not meant to mess with them. Also, make sure to check [this tutorial](http://www.liferay.com/en/community/wiki/-/wiki/1071674/Custom+queries+in+Liferay+5.2)

Answer (score 0):

When you make a call to Liferay *Util class the transaction is never propagated.

The same issue occurs if you use a *ServiceUtil into a *ServiceImpl.

In your case i think that you can use the EmployeePersistence that must be injected in your EmployeeLocalServiceImpl.

Replace this code : `return EmployeeFinderUtil.getEmployee();`

by this one `return this.employeePersistence.getEmployee();`

Answer (score 0):

Using Liferay 6.1.20 and for the build I used maven with Liferay Plugin Version 6.2.10.9.

Make sure your EmployeeFinderImpl class is in your service.persistence package/folder.

When the service builder is run it generates the interface for your EmployeeFinderImpl. Additionally it adds code to instantiate it into your EmployeeLocalServiceImpl.

EmployeeLocalServiceImpl should already have your EmployeeFinderImpl class instantiated within it and you can change your code to following and it will work.

```
public class EmployeeLocalServiceImpl extends EmployeeLocalServiceBaseImpl {
    /*
     * NOTE FOR DEVELOPERS:
     *
     * Never reference this interface directly. Always use {@link com.mallyas.corpserver.emco.mis.service.EmployeeLocalServiceUtil} to access the employee local service.
     */

    public List getEmployee() throws PortalException, SystemException, RemoteException {

        return employeeFinder.getEmployee();
    }
 ...
}
```